# Css Position Relative/Absolute is disturbing the Layout

Tags: html, css, css-position

Please checkout the following fiddle
HTML structure and Css is almost same. that i am using in my project.
Currently i have 3 sections in my design
HEADER 
Portfolio
Slider Troubling section

I am using bootstrap 3 latest version.

I have given position relative to Portfolio section and its inner block to position absolute with top: -50px;

Every thing is fine here. but problem comes when i add new section "Slider". It is coming over the Portfolio section. I have tried giving it position and different block properties. but still slider section is coming over the portfolio section. When i remove Positions from Portfolio section 
the Slider section goes back to it normal position which is what i want.
Can anyone please check the following fiddle and tell me what i am doing wrong.
Design is like that Portfolio section is little bit over the header. that's why i am using position.

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29616/embed/"></script>
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29616/
```

Comment: You cannot embed a fiddle into a question. You need to add the code manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather not use position: absolute where it's not needed because it breaks the flow. You need only position relative or negative margin-top to move the element up. See example https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29623/

```
<header class="container-fluid header">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="container">
  <div class="row position-relative">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 position-relative-col">
      <div class="height">
      <h2>Some Portfolio items here</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container trouble">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>Slider Troubling section</h3>
  </div>
</section>

/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
.header {
  background: lightblue;
  padding:25px;
}
.position-relative {
  position:relative;
}
.position-relative-col {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
.trouble {
  background: darkblue;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: white;
}
.height {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hi..!! This solution works. I have one question? is there any reason to not use position:absolute ??? because when i removed position absolute from my code and gave top:-50px to my relative positioned element layout is fixed.

Comment: Because if you set position: absolute you break the flow of elements and as a result you have broken layout. So if you can use position relative or negative margin-top do it for sure. It'll be correct for 100%. If it works for you, mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for explaination.

Answer (score 0):

try add to the container class height property. It should work:

```
.container{
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I gave .container a fixed height. but since container height will change according to portfolio items. so i think there should be another way?

Comment: so maybe its better not to use position absolute but instead use relative and positioned the container with margin.

Answer (score 0):

Check my update I hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29626/

what I did are put the slider and portfolio into the same tag that using `position:relative` and `top: -50px;`

Comment: Thanks. You just solved my problem. But I have a one question.              Why you didn't use position absolute on the inner div and gave top:-50px to it? You just directly give top: -50px to position relative ? is there anything i should know ? In my original project code i only removed position:absolute and give  top:-50px to my relative positioned element and layout got fixed.

Comment: I dunno how to explain this, let my try... I always use position absolute for element that need to be placed right on top of another element more like layer on photoshop I guess. You should try how the absolute position by putting it in the element with relative position then compare it with element without position.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the bootstrap 3 grid wrong. For each row you have to add a `row` class and for each item in the `row` class you have to use the class `col-*-*`. I have written based on your code some new code with the proper use of bootstrap grid.

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29627/

Please let me know if this is not good, and what you try to achieve instead.

Comment: Thanks for grid usage suggestion. but this is not what i am looking for.